# Export contact detail to URL after Save

Tags: apex, trigger, field-update

Im all looking for the following functionality:

1) User clicks Save on Contact Page
2) If a Picklist value
    equals,    for example, 'Left Company' or 'No Interest', then....
3) A Trigger    fires that exports certain fields to a URL (which in
    turn is imported    into another instance of SFDC)

In a nutshell, my organisation uses a main database of contacts, that we use to run seperate campaigns in individual instances of SFDC, we are using this functionality to export 'confirmed contacts' into a main database or records to ensure that our main list of contacts is always up to date.

Any help on this would be very much appreciated, as I am struggling to get my head around Triggers

Cheers

Comment: Have you considered Salesforce to Salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to use a trigger, you'll want to create a trigger that fires on AfterInsert, AfterUpdate which tests the field you mention in trigger.new for picklist values that match your criteria where they didn't previously match your criteria in trigger.old (can only compare in the AfterUpdate context). You obviously don't want to send the record twice since it could be updated for other reasons, thus the check against trigger.old if an update.

For the records that match your criteria, you create a list of them and make a callout to a Global Class containing an asynchronous method with @future annotation that also has webservices modifer that will send the information to your other database via either REST or SOAP. See [Apex Web Services and Callouts](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts) for more information on this.